# Could not find the required *.deps.json for .NET Core AWS Serverless Application

Tags: .net-core, aws-sam

- Create new Visual Studio solution based on template 'AWS Serverless Application (.NET Core - C#)
- Scaffold an ASP.NET Core Web API
- Run `sam local start-api -t serverless.template` in the project folder
- Make a GET request to http://localhost:3000/api/values
- Results in error:

  > Invalid API Gateway Response Keys: {'errorMessage', 'errorType'} in {'errorType': 'LambdaException', 'errorMessage': "Could not find the required 'AWSServerless1.deps.json'.  This file should be present at the root of the deployment package."}

I haven't made any changes to the solution created from the Visual Studio template.

[image: Could not find required deps json]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed by updating `serverless.template` to contain:

`"CodeUri": "bin/Release/netcoreapp3.1"`

Then: `dotnet publish -c Release` before running the `sam local start-api -t serverless.template` command.